# saving canvas contents to a file and reading from a file

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to get individual objects in a tkinter canvas so that I can pickle dump them using Python, and pickle load them from a file and put it back on canvas. I could not find a canvas method that gives me an object based on ID or Tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_all` method of the canvas to return an identifier for each item on the canvas. You can then use `itemconfigure` to get the attributes of each item.